# Returning a float value out of a UITextField

Tags: iphone, objective-c

What would be the best way to return a float Value from a UITextField ?

I`m using :

(dN being the textField)

```
[dN floatValue];
```

but it`s returning :

*'UITextField' may not respond to '-floatValue' as a warning*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[dN.text floatValue];
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to have a NSString intermediate.

```
NSString *myString = dn.text;
float g = [myString floatValue];
```